# chrome adds carriage returns using execCommand('copy')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, execcommand

When I use document.execCommand('copy'), chrome adds a carriage return at the end of the copied text (which isnt actually in the HTLM, while IE does not (correct behavior).
Am I doing something wrong?

```
   function copycode(){

    var length=this.id.length;
    var preid = this.id.substring(0,length-1);
    var textnode=document.getElementById(preid);
    textnode.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    var range = document.createRange();  
    range.selectNode(textnode);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    var succeed;
    try {
      succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } 
    catch(e) {
      succeed = false;
    }
    textnode.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies not within the execution of the copy command, "document.execCommand('copy')", this works fine. The range selection is the problem.

I encountered the same problem and I solved it by using: element.SELECT(). For example:

Create a textarea and place it off screen (hiding won't work). Set the value and select the complete textarea.

```
    var textarea = document.createElement( "textarea" );
    textarea.style.height = "0px";
    textarea.style.left = "-100px";
    textarea.style.opacity = "0";
    textarea.style.position = "fixed";
    textarea.style.top = "-100px";
    textarea.style.width = "0px";
    document.body.appendChild( textarea );

    textarea.value = textnode.innerHTML;
    textarea.select();

    document.execCommand('copy');
```